# XSL not copying all templates on each record

Tags: xml, templates, unix, xslt

I'm a newbie to XSL and I am writing a Unix script so I hope you can help me out. My issue:
I have an XML which I need to parse to TXT, I'm using xsltproc to parse it But in an XML containing only 1 record it works fine, but with multiple records it strips my first xsl:template.

```
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<flxint>
    <app>
        <comp>269</comp>
        <signal>ITMAML</signal>
        <sigref>000000003</sigref>
        <date>20130606</date>
        <time>115316</time>
        <id>FTZ</id>
        <duns/>
        <revision>007</revision>
        <data>
            <rec>
                <rpos>1</rpos>
                <change>UPDATE</change>
                <itemdef>
                    <item>MOT-11022H</item>
                    <cmpn>11022H</cmpn>
                    <desc>ASSY,CAR KIT,EIHF,T305,SELF IN</desc>
                    <type>Purchased</type>
                    <item_group>MOT01P</item_group>
                    <inv_uom>ea</inv_uom>
                    <revi>A</revi>
                    <wh>269021</wh>
                    <material/>
                    <standard/>
                    <prod_type>STD</prod_type>
                    <item_signal/>
                    <item_wght>1</item_wght>
                    <item_wght_unit>kg</item_wght_unit>
                    <item_text/>
                    <ipld>
                        <rpd_plid>TBD</rpd_plid>
                        <mpnr>0</mpnr>
                    </ipld>
                    <ipd>
                        <order_ltime>0</order_ltime>
                    </ipd>
                    <shelf_life>NA</shelf_life>
                    <shelf_per>0</shelf_per>
                    <item_height>0</item_height>
                    <item_width>0</item_width>
                    <item_depth>0</item_depth>
                    <item_wght_unit>lb</item_wght_unit>
                    <item_dim_unit>ft</item_dim_unit>
                    <abc_code>C</abc_code>
                    <hml_code/>
                    <buyer>TBD</buyer>
                    <inspect>N</inspect>
                    <coo/>
                    <rec_early>365</rec_early>
                    <rec_late>365</rec_late>
                    <rec_over>0</rec_over>
                    <rec_under>100</rec_under>
                    <pur_pricgrp>N/A</pur_pricgrp>
                    <pur_statgrp>PUR</pur_statgrp>
                    <pur_statgrp_desc>Purchase Statistic Group</pur_statgrp_desc>
                    <contact>
                        <name>TO BE DEFINED</name>
                        <phone/>
                        <email/>
                    </contact>
                    <iod>
                        <order_int>5</order_int>
                        <order_inc>1</order_inc>
                        <min_qty>1</min_qty>
                        <plid>TBD</plid>
                    </iod>
                    <std_costs>
                        <std_cost>1</std_cost>
                        <std_curr>USD</std_curr>
                        <std_mat>1</std_mat>
                        <std_op>0</std_op>
                        <last_calc_date>20130326</last_calc_date>
                        <last_calc_date_time>120035</last_calc_date_time>
                    </std_costs>
                    <sim_pur_pric>
                        <spp_code>001</spp_code>
                        <spp_price>1</spp_price>
                        <spp_unit>ea</spp_unit>
                        <spp_curr>USD</spp_curr>
                        <spp_cost_comp>001</spp_cost_comp>
                    </sim_pur_pric>
                    <std_costs>
                        <std_cost>0</std_cost>
                        <std_curr/>
                    </std_costs>
                    <storage_conditions/>
                    <rohs>N</rohs>
                    <com_code/>
                    <ean/>
                    <eccn/>
                    <upc/>
                    <cust_po/>
                    <cust_po_pos/>
                    <sel_code/>
                    <consum_code/>
                    <rbom_famitem/>
                    <alt_desc>ASSY,CAR KIT,EIHF,T305,SELF INSTL AR</alt_desc>
                    <aml/>
                    <ics>
                        <code>MOT</code>
                        <bpid/>
                        <citem>11022H</citem>
                    </ics>
                    <item_data_additions>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>1</attrno>
                            <attrname>FTZ Reporting Status</attrname>
                            <attrval>Y</attrval>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>2</attrno>
                            <attrname>HTS Value</attrname>
                            <attrval>8517620050</attrval>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>3</attrno>
                            <attrname>Arctic Fox / Common</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>4</attrno>
                            <attrname>(4) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>5</attrno>
                            <attrname>(5) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>6</attrno>
                            <attrname>(6) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>7</attrno>
                            <attrname>(7) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>8</attrno>
                            <attrname>(8) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>9</attrno>
                            <attrname>(9) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>10</attrno>
                            <attrname>(10) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>11</attrno>
                            <attrname>(11) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>12</attrno>
                            <attrname>(12) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>13</attrno>
                            <attrname>(13) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>14</attrno>
                            <attrname>(14) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>15</attrno>
                            <attrname>(15) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>16</attrno>
                            <attrname>(16) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>17</attrno>
                            <attrname>(17) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>18</attrno>
                            <attrname>(18) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>19</attrno>
                            <attrname>(19) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>20</attrno>
                            <attrname>(20) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                    </item_data_additions>
                    <eng>
                        <eng_rev>
                            <revi>A</revi>
                            <dsca>DAL078075E</dsca>
                            <orno/>
                            <eff_date>20130312</eff_date>
                            <eff_date_time>180825</eff_date_time>
                            <exp_date/>
                            <exp_date_time/>
                            <revi_status>RELEASED</revi_status>
                            <draw_loc/>
                            <cad_date/>
                            <cad_date_time/>
                            <draw/>
                        </eng_rev>
                    </eng>
                    <aml_add_attrs/>
                    <sel_code_dsca/>
                    <rohs_insp>No</rohs_insp>
                    <log_grpcode/>
                </itemdef>
            </rec>
            <rec>
                <rpos>2</rpos>
                <change>UPDATE</change>
                <itemdef>
                    <item>MOT-11052N</item>
                    <cmpn>11052N</cmpn>
                    <desc>ACCY,ENT/CONCTIV,BT HSET,H560,</desc>
                    <type>Purchased</type>
                    <item_group>MOT01P</item_group>
                    <inv_uom>ea</inv_uom>
                    <revi>A</revi>
                    <wh>269021</wh>
                    <material/>
                    <standard/>
                    <prod_type>STD</prod_type>
                    <item_signal/>
                    <item_wght>1</item_wght>
                    <item_wght_unit>kg</item_wght_unit>
                    <item_text/>
                    <ipld>
                        <rpd_plid>TBD</rpd_plid>
                        <mpnr>0</mpnr>
                    </ipld>
                    <ipd>
                        <order_ltime>0</order_ltime>
                    </ipd>
                    <shelf_life>NA</shelf_life>
                    <shelf_per>0</shelf_per>
                    <item_height>0</item_height>
                    <item_width>0</item_width>
                    <item_depth>0</item_depth>
                    <item_wght_unit>lb</item_wght_unit>
                    <item_dim_unit>ft</item_dim_unit>
                    <abc_code>C</abc_code>
                    <hml_code/>
                    <buyer>TBD</buyer>
                    <inspect>N</inspect>
                    <coo/>
                    <rec_early>365</rec_early>
                    <rec_late>365</rec_late>
                    <rec_over>0</rec_over>
                    <rec_under>100</rec_under>
                    <pur_pricgrp>N/A</pur_pricgrp>
                    <pur_statgrp>PUR</pur_statgrp>
                    <pur_statgrp_desc>Purchase Statistic Group</pur_statgrp_desc>
                    <contact>
                        <name>TO BE DEFINED</name>
                        <phone/>
                        <email/>
                    </contact>
                    <iod>
                        <order_int>5</order_int>
                        <order_inc>1</order_inc>
                        <min_qty>1</min_qty>
                        <plid>TBD</plid>
                    </iod>
                    <std_costs>
                        <std_cost>1</std_cost>
                        <std_curr>USD</std_curr>
                        <std_mat>1</std_mat>
                        <std_op>0</std_op>
                        <last_calc_date>20130326</last_calc_date>
                        <last_calc_date_time>120035</last_calc_date_time>
                    </std_costs>
                    <sim_pur_pric>
                        <spp_code>001</spp_code>
                        <spp_price>1</spp_price>
                        <spp_unit>ea</spp_unit>
                        <spp_curr>USD</spp_curr>
                        <spp_cost_comp>001</spp_cost_comp>
                    </sim_pur_pric>
                    <std_costs>
                        <std_cost>0</std_cost>
                        <std_curr/>
                    </std_costs>
                    <storage_conditions/>
                    <rohs>N</rohs>
                    <com_code/>
                    <ean/>
                    <eccn/>
                    <upc/>
                    <cust_po/>
                    <cust_po_pos/>
                    <sel_code/>
                    <consum_code/>
                    <rbom_famitem/>
                    <alt_desc>ACCY,ENT/CONCTIV,BT HSET,H560,SLVR ARG</alt_desc>
                    <aml/>
                    <ics>
                        <code>MOT</code>
                        <bpid/>
                        <citem>11052N</citem>
                    </ics>
                    <item_data_additions>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>1</attrno>
                            <attrname>FTZ Reporting Status</attrname>
                            <attrval>Y</attrval>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>2</attrno>
                            <attrname>HTS Value</attrname>
                            <attrval>8517620050</attrval>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>3</attrno>
                            <attrname>Arctic Fox / Common</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>4</attrno>
                            <attrname>(4) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>5</attrno>
                            <attrname>(5) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>6</attrno>
                            <attrname>(6) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>7</attrno>
                            <attrname>(7) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>8</attrno>
                            <attrname>(8) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>9</attrno>
                            <attrname>(9) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>10</attrno>
                            <attrname>(10) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>11</attrno>
                            <attrname>(11) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>12</attrno>
                            <attrname>(12) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>13</attrno>
                            <attrname>(13) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>14</attrno>
                            <attrname>(14) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>15</attrno>
                            <attrname>(15) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>16</attrno>
                            <attrname>(16) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>17</attrno>
                            <attrname>(17) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>18</attrno>
                            <attrname>(18) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>19</attrno>
                            <attrname>(19) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                        <item_data>
                            <attrno>20</attrno>
                            <attrname>(20) Not Defined</attrname>
                            <attrval/>
                        </item_data>
                    </item_data_additions>
                    <eng>
                        <eng_rev>
                            <revi>A</revi>
                            <dsca>DAL078075E</dsca>
                            <orno/>
                            <eff_date>20130312</eff_date>
                            <eff_date_time>180826</eff_date_time>
                            <exp_date/>
                            <exp_date_time/>
                            <revi_status>RELEASED</revi_status>
                            <draw_loc/>
                            <cad_date/>


                    <cad_date_time/>
                        <draw/>
                    </eng_rev>
                </eng>
                <aml_add_attrs/>
                <sel_code_dsca/>
                <rohs_insp>No</rohs_insp>
                <log_grpcode/>
            </itemdef>
        </rec>
                </data>
        </app>
</flxint>`
```

Here's my XSL so far:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="flxint">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="app"/>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="app">
    <xsl:text>10563|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='date'/><xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='time'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="data">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="rec"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="rec">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="itemdef"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="itemdef">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="ics"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>IM|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='desc'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='inv_uom'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='item_wght'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='item_wght_unit'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>USD|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>E|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>HTSNumber|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='coo'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="aml"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sim_pur_pric"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ics"> 
        <xsl:value-of select='citem'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="aml">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="aml_rec"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="aml_rec"> 
        <xsl:value-of select='add_item_info'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sim_pur_pric">
        <xsl:value-of select='spp_price'/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>USD|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>0|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>|&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's the output, the first row is OK, but not the second one and so

```
10563|20130606T115316|11022H||IM|ASSY,CAR KIT,EIHF,T305,SELF IN|ea|1|kg|0|USD||||E|||||HTSNumber|||1|0|USD|0|0|||||||0||0|||||
11052N||IM|ACCY,ENT/CONCTIV,BT HSET,H560,|ea|1|kg|0|USD||||E|||||HTSNumber|||1|0|USD|0|0|||||||0||0|||||
11054N||IM|ACCY,MOB/VOICE,BT HSET,H15,LA|ea|1|kg|0|USD||||E|||||HTSNumber|||1|0|USD|0|0|||||||0||0|||||
11061N||IM|ACCY,MUSIC/ENT,SPKR,EQ5,COLDPL|ea|1|kg|0|USD||||E|||||HTSNumber|||||||1|0|USD|0|0|||||||0||0|||||
```

Comment: A good idea is to only post the necessary parts of your code/output. There's a lot of XML data in your post, and it would be worth shortening if your problem could still be replicated with only the essentials.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. I have the xml files loaded up in my environment. Please explain what your desired output is. Multiple records of what... flxint? app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation here is, that you like to have the same "data structure" in each output line (for each record).
What you are missing in the second line seems to be the data from "app".

This could be done with small changes to your xlst.

Split your app tmeplate into two:

```
<xsl:template match="app">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="app" mode="print">
    <xsl:text>10563|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='date'/>
    <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='time'/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

First one only to apply templates, second one to print the data.

Call the second one from your itemdef template.

```
<xsl:template match="itemdef">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::app" mode="print"/>
    <!-- rest of temdef template -->
```

Comment: Great! hr_117 you saved me! Definitely I need a good course of XSL. Thank you so much!